# No Strawberry seeds in Year 5

Tags: harvest-moon-two-towns

I am currently playing [Harvest Moon:The Tale of Two Towns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvest_Moon_DS:_The_Tale_of_Two_Towns) (US release).
I am living in Konohana.

According to all of the FAQ sites out there, Strawberry seeds should become available in Spring of year 3. I am in year 5, and have been visiting Gombe's seed shop 5 days a week (it is closed for two days) for the last three years and I have never been able to find strawberry seeds.

Is this a known bug? Does anyone know of another way to get Strawberry seeds?
Some of the ways I have tried (unsuccessfully):

1. Lose the cooking contest in Spring and hope for some Strawberry seeds as a consolation prize
2. Look for Strawberries as a reward from a message board task, and hope to use my seed maker
3. keep checking the Seed store every day

In year 5, spring, the crop festival involves strawberries, and I am quite out of ideas at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Strawberry seeds finally showed up in Gombe's shop on <kbd>Spring 26<sup>th</sup></kbd>
Which didn't help me because the Spring Crop Festival for year 5 was on <kbd>Spring 25<sup>th</sup></kbd>
So I suspect that while this is not a severe bug, it does appear to be a bug of some sort.
If you have played this game to Year 5 and have gotten hold of Strawberries sooner than year 5, please leave a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

I got my strawberry seeds in year 3 pretty early in the spring. 
The only "reliable" method to get these is Gonbe's shop which seems to be completely random.
In year 4 I got the seeds very late and I checked every day (when the Shop was open).
So we can conclude that we need a little bit of luck to get the seeds we want.

Comment: Yah, I think the original poster's problem was just bad luck. For what its worth I have strawberry seeds in my Fall of Year 2 save. Must have gotten  one as a consolation prize.